# How to run multiple tags from testrunner class file in cucumber framework using @tags?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions( plugin = {"pretty","html:target/html/automation"},
                features = {"resource/***.feature"},
                glue={},
                tags={"@login","@Products"}
        )
```

This is my feature files

@login

Feature: Login to Application

Scenario: this is verify the application is logged successfully
    Given Navigate to Panasonic application
    Then Verify the title of the application
    Then Logout the application

@Products

Feature: Login to Application

Background: user should be navigate to home page of application

Given User login to home page with valid credentials

When click the catalog link on home page

Scenario : To verify whether able to create more than ten products in products page

And check the sub menu of catalog is displaying in header

And check the My product catalog table

Comment: you have not specified the glue code which is why probably it is not working. please specify the glue code and that should be it

Comment: @MrunalGosar what i have to specify in glue code? is package name of step definition? or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample cucumber Junit runner template:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:features/*.feature" }, glue = "packagename(s) or class name(s) containing the step definitions", plugin = {
        "pretty:target/prettyReport.txt", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json", "rerun:target/rerun.txt",
        "junit:target/junit-report.xml", "testng:target/testng-output.xml" }, monochrome = true, tags = {"~@Ignore"})
public class FeatureRunnerTest {

}
```

Hope this helps!! 
EDIT: "~" symbol..is used for negation..that is run all the features except one's marked with Ignore tag..On the other hand u can specify list of tags in the tags attribute comma seperated to run only those tests

Comment: Now i got some clear points from your comment. I need clarification in your comment. Here u have mentioned tags = {"~@Ignore"} instead of this tags, shall i use my tags={"~@login","~@Products"} like this???

Answer (score 6):

For multiple tags Cucumber uses logical AND and logical OR.
For example, the below works fine for me.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-report.html"},
        features= "Features",
        glue= {"com.cucumber.stepdefinition"},
        tags= "@RegressionTest or @SmokeTest"
        )
public class TestRunner {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the below implemtation of multi tag form cucumber rummer:

> @CucumberOptions(
> features = "src/test/java/features",
> glue="stepDefinations",
> tags = "@Test_Working_Calendar,@Test_email_tempalte",
> plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber"
> ,"json:target/cucumber.json"
> ,"junit:target/cukes.xml"
> ,"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"})

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(

        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "stepDefinitions",          
        tags="@grup1 or @grup2",                                                             
        dryRun = false
)
```

Comment: I don't understand why people post wrong codes that don't work.but this code works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

tags="test1 or @test2"
Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
@CucumberOptions(
     /* tags = {"@SmokeTest","@Register"},*/
     features = "src/test/Features",
     glue = "",
     plugin = { "pretty","json:target/stepdefinition.json"})
```

I commented the tags line and the test cases ran in order for me. Try this and let me know.